# Why is Pandas converting datetimes to float in aggregate function

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

**Updated Post:**

I would like to know why Pandas is transforming a `datetime` column into a `float` one.

The code below reproduces the issue I am having.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2012-01-01", periods=12).values.reshape(3,4), columns=list('abcd'))

print "Original:", {col: df[col].dtype for col in df.columns}

df['c'].loc[1] = pd.NaT
df['d'].loc[1] = pd.NaT

df['ab'] = df[['a','b']].min(1)
df['cd'] = df[['c','d']].min(1)

print "New:", {col: df[col].dtype for col in df.columns}
```

This prints:

```
Original: {'a': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'c': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'b': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'd': dtype('<M8[ns]')}
New: {'a': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'c': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'b': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'd': dtype('<M8[ns]'), 'cd': dtype('float64'), 'ab': dtype('<M8[ns]')}
```

Note that column `ab` is of type `dtype('<M8[ns]')` but `cd` is of type `dtype('float64')`.

Why is Pandas changing the type?

**Original Post:**

I am running very simple code:

```
x['new1'] = x[['startDate1','stopDate1']].min(1)
x['new2'] = x[['startDate2','stopDate2']].min(1)
```

Where x looks something like this:

```
ID         startDate1    stopDate1    startDate2    stopDate2

0          2000-01-01   2000-03-05    2005-01-01   2006-03-05
               ...          ...          ...          ...
40053      1997-01-01   2011-03-05    2012-01-01   2012-03-05
```

Running `x[colName].dtype` on all original columns returns `dtype('<M8[ns]')`.

However, `x['new1'].dtype` does not match `x['new2'].dtype` where the former is `dtype('<M8[ns]')` but the latter is **`dtype('float64')`**.

I've fixed it with this line, but I want to know why this is happening as it makes little sense to me.

```
x['new2'] = pd.to_datetime(x[['startDate2','stopDate2']].min(1))
```

There are a lot of rows, so I can't go through all of them. **What does this imply about the `startDate2` and `stopDate2` columns?**

**Update to Original Post:**
The only difference I found between the columns is that the `stopDate2` has at least one row with `NaT`. Removing the `NaT`s removes the problem, but I can't reproduce it with dummy data.

Comment: could you add code that creates the array x to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I tried to simplify it (the actual code is very long) - it's a CSV import that gets processed many times over.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? I cannot reproduce this with 0.16-0.18

Comment: It's version `0.16.2`.

Comment: @TimY Try to create some dummy data that reproduces the problem. Eg `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("2012-01-01", periods=20).values.reshape(5,4), columns=list('abcd')); df[['a', 'b']].min(1)` does not reproduce it for me

Comment: I tried to do this, but if I knew how to produce this problem, I would have phrased my question in a less vague manner. I honestly have no idea what could be causing it. Perhaps you can think of some tests I could run on the data?

Comment: @TimY could you share your dataframe x via dropbox or something?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm allowed to do this. Let me see if I can isolate the problem to a sub-section.

Comment: @TimY The dummy data I posted does not reproduce it for you as well? Can you show `df.info()`? Try to limit your data to a minimal subset that reproduces the problem, then try to recreate it with some code.

Comment: Okay, I got it. There appears to be one `NaT` value in the pile. Still I don't understand why Pandas is transforming it into `floats`.

Comment: I'll try to write some code that can reproduce this

Comment: I've managed to reproduce it now.

Comment: @TimY Good find! I can now also reproduce this, also with the latest pandas release. This seems definitely like a bug, would you like to open an issue at https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/?

Comment: Yes, I probably will. I might do that later, but I'm a bit busy now.

Comment: Can you link the github bug report here? So that we can follow the progress of it.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, it's probably a bug, due to the presence of a `NaN`, in case you wanted to have a work around, you can do:

```
df[["c", "d"]].min(axis=1).astype("<M8[ns]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Related problem. Using pandas 0.18.1. See that `df.timestamp` has different types in the two different scenarios:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(250).reshape(50,5), 
                      index=pd.date_range('1/1/2016', periods=50, freq='H' ),
                      columns=list('ABCDE'))
df['timestamp'] = df.index

print(df.timestamp.resample('30min',label='right').last().head(3))
print('==========')
print(df.timestamp.resample('2H',label='right').last().head(3))
```

output:

```
2016-01-01 00:30:00    1.451606e+18
2016-01-01 01:00:00             NaN
2016-01-01 01:30:00    1.451610e+18
Freq: 30T, Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
==========
2016-01-01 02:00:00   2016-01-01 01:00:00
2016-01-01 04:00:00   2016-01-01 03:00:00
2016-01-01 06:00:00   2016-01-01 05:00:00
Freq: 2H, Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Also found the bug report related to this issue:
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12941